# Convert array to a string inside AutocompleteArrayInput

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to use parse and format to convert the input from AutocompleteArrayInput before storing the data in my database(postgres with graphql API), but i keep getting a error when the component try to map the input.

AutocompleteArrayInput outputs an array and I need to convert it to a single string so I can **store a colection of tags in my database**, i know this is not the best solution, but i dont have control over the database.

```js
<AutocompleteArrayInput 
  parse={v => v.join("-")}
  // format={v => v.split("-")}
  label="Areas Involved" 
  source="areas_involved" 
  validate={required()} 
  choices={areas_involved_choices} 
/>
```

Comment: Could we see the actual error you get ?

Comment: The console just output "TypeError: v.split is not a function", i've tried to stringify the array, but it still not working.

Comment: Could you `format={v => { console.log(v); return v; }}` ? And show us the output ?